# Where are Xposed modules stored?

Tags: xposed-framework

I've installed an Xposed module that messed up with my `com.android.systemui`.

So I thought maybe I could find the module via the File Manager in TWRP recovery and delete it.

My question is: **Where are these modules stored?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured how to solve it, but first you need access to your "inner" Android files (all the system stuff). You just need to navigate to `/data/app`, find the package of the app (or the module) and delete it.